# Get a reference to the more navigation controller in UITabbbarController

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, tabbarcontroller

i will like to get reference to the more navigation controller in ios swift project or simply get reference to the tabs(2) in it. i have a UITabbarController with 6 tabs, so the last two are hidden in the more navigation controller. i tried this:

```
let firstViewController: NavigationController1 = childViewControllers[4] as! NavigationController1
```

i get the error:

this gives index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3] error

Any solution will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your tabbbarcontroller may have only 4 tabs right now. Print childViewControllers.count and check.

Comment: it works on ipad because ipad can contain the 6 tabs in one screen. why dont u try it and see

Comment: have you logged count of childViewControllers for iphone? If ipad is working then in iphone it should work, So first check count of viewcontrollers.

Comment: yes the count is 4. but my problem is why cant i have access to the remaining 2? its very easy to recreate. if you want i can send you a sample project. you can just create 6 tabs and try getting access to the last 2.

Comment: you said last 2 is hidden in more navigation controller, So you can't get it through 'childViewControllers[4]', you have to get it where you have stored or referenced.

Comment: am not the one who made the more navigation controller. its done automatically by iOS, thats what am talking about. Thats why i said it works fine on iPad, that can contain all the 6 tabs. This is really a basic issue i expect anyone who has made tabbar should have encountered the problem.